# Custom keyboard set visibility gone when touch event dispatch from editText

Tags: android, keyboard

I want to mimic android keyboard behavior when handling touch event. The android keyboard always hide every time I click somewhere else other the edit text and the keyboard. So far, I could mimic that's behavior using `dispatchTouchEvent`

Since it will detect for any dispatch touch even, whenever I click my keyboard button then it will close the keyboard it self. I wanna check if I click somewhere else other than my keyboard then hide the keyboard, else keep the keyboard on. I think I just missed piece of code and I can't find it what i missed here. It just need one single step to accomplish this. Please help.

Here my keyboard looks like

[image: custom keyboard]

and here what i did so far

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (getCurrentFocus() != null) {
        View view = getCurrentFocus();
        //im not sure this condition would help
        if (view == null) {
            keyboard.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

I can get the view object but i cant determine which view that i need to keep my keyboard on.

The other code (variable declaration)

```
PhoneKeyboard pk;
InputConnection ic;
LinearLayout keyboard;

pk = findViewById(R.id.phone_keyboard);
ic = phone_no.onCreateInputConnection(new EditorInfo());
pk.setInputConnection(ic);
```

Handling back pressed (mimic the android keyboard behavior)

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    if(keyboard.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
        super.onBackPressed();
    else
        keyboard.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

How I handle request on the editText to make my keyboard visible

```
phone_no.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
                    android.content.Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);

            if(view.equals(phone_no) && keyboard.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                phone_no.requestFocus();
                keyboard.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

How I handle submit / enter event at my custom keyboard (for who need the solution for custom keyboard, maybe this post can help other:) )

```
phone_no.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
                    android.content.Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);

            if(view.equals(phone_no) && keyboard.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                phone_no.requestFocus();
                keyboard.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Here is my snippet code for the keyboard layout view

```
    <include
            layout="@layout/layout_keyboard_phone_no"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Ps. I also have base activity and it extends to all my activity (if your solution required the base activity)

## Update 1

I have try this method

```
 phone_no.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) {
                keyboard.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });
```

Is doing the same thing with the onDispatch event, whenever I click number on my custom keyboard, it also hide the keyboard. I need to check if the view others than the edit text and my custom keyboard then hide the keyboard else keep the keyboard on. Thank you